# Julia: using CurveFit package non linear

Tags: julia, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

why the code below does not work?

```
xa = [0  0.200000000000000 0.400000000000000  1.00000000000000  1.60000000000000  1.80000000000000  2.00000000000000  2.60000000000000  2.80000000000000  3.00000000000000  3.80000000000000  4.80000000000000  5.00000000000000  5.20000000000000  6.00000000000000  6.20000000000000  7.40000000000000  7.60000000000000  7.80000000000000  8.60000000000000  8.80000000000000  9.00000000000000  9.20000000000000  9.40000000000000  10.0000000000000  10.6000000000000  10.8000000000000  11.2000000000000  11.6000000000000  11.8000000000000  12.2000000000000  12.4000000000000];

ya = [-0.183440428023042  -0.131101157495126  0.0268875670852843 0.300000000120000  0.579048247883555  0.852605831272159  0.935180993484717  1.13328608090532  1.26893326843583  1.10202945535186  1.09201137189664  1.14279083803453  0.811302535321072  0.909735376251797  0.417067545528244  0.460107770989798  -0.516307074859654  -0.333994077331822  -0.504124744955962  -0.945794320817293  -0.915934553082780  -0.975458595671737  -1.09943707404275  -1.11254211607374  -1.29739980589100  -1.23440439602665  -0.953807504156356  -1.12240274852172  -0.609284630192522  -0.592560286759450  -0.402521296049042  -0.510090363150962];

x0 = vec(xa) 
y0 = vec(ya)
fun(x,a) = a[1].*sin(a[2].*x - a[3])
a0 = [1,2,3] 
eps = 0.000001 
maxiter=200 
coefs, converged, iter = CurveFit.nonlinear_fit(x0 , fun , a0 , eps, maxiter ) 
y0b = fit(x0) 
Winston.plot(x0, y0, "ob", x0, y0b, "r-", linewidth=3)
```

> Error: LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Array{Float64,1}) This may have arisen from
>   a call to the constructor Float64(...), since type constructors fall
>   back to convert methods. Closest candidates are: call{T}(::Type{T},
>   ::Any) convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int8)
>   convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int16)
>
> while loading In[269], in expression starting on line 8
>        in nonlinear_fit at /home/jmarcellopereira/.julia/v0.4/CurveFit/src/nonlinfit.jl:75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fun` function has to return a residual value `r` of type `Float64`, calculated at each iteration of the data, as follows:

```
r = y - fun(x, coefs)
```

so your function `y=a1*sin(x*a2-a3)` will be defined as:

```
fun(x,a) = x[2]-a[1]*sin(a[2]*x[1] - a[3])
```

Where:

```
  x[2] is a value of 'y' vector  
  x[1] is a value of 'x' vector  
  a[...] is the set of parameters
```

The `fun` function has to return a single `Float64`, so the operators can't be  'dot version' (`.*`).

By calling the *nonlinear_fit* function, the first parameter must be an array Nx2, with the first column containing N values of `x` and the second, containing N values of `y`, so you must concatenate the two vectors `x` and `y` in a two columns array:

```
xy = [x y]
```

and finally, call the function:

```
coefs, converged, iter = CurveFit.nonlinear_fit(xy , fun , a0 , eps, maxiter )
```

Answering to your comment about the returned coefficients are not correct:

The `y = 1 * sin (x * a2-a3)` is a **harmonic** function, so the coefficients returning from the function call, depend **heavily** on the parameter `a0` (*"initial guess for each fitting parameter"*) you will send as the third parameter (with `maxiter=200_000`):

```
a0=[1.5, 1.5, 1.0]  
coefficients: [0.2616335317043578, 1.1471991302529982,0.7048665905560775]

a0=[100.,100.,100.]  
coefficients: [-0.4077952060368059, 90.52328921205392, 96.75331155303707]

a0=[1.2, 0.5, 0.5]  
coefficients: [1.192007321713507, 0.49426296880933257, 0.19863645732313934]
```

I think the results you're getting are harmonics, as the graph:

[image: Plot result of harmonics]

Where:

```
blue line:  
f1(xx)=0.2616335317043578*sin(xx*1.1471991302529982-0.7048665905560775)

yellow line:
f2(xx)=1.192007321713507*sin(xx*0.49426296880933257-0.19863645732313934)

pink line:
f3(xx)=-0.4077952060368059*sin(xx*90.52328921205392-96.75331155303707)

blue dots are your initial data.
```

The graph was generated with [Gadfly](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl):

```
plot(layer(x=x,y=y,Geom.point),layer([f1,f2,f3],0.0, 15.0,Geom.line))
```

<sub>tested with Julia Version 0.4.3</sub>

Comment: olá alexandre. 

rapz so voce para salvar minha vida ;).

de fato não havia reparado na caracteristica harmonica da função seno e por isso os valores iniciais tem importancia fundamental nos coeficientes finais. A explicação ficou excelente, recomendo postar como tutorial na pagina do curvefit no github, pois para os "juleiros" de primeiro código como eu, um tutorial desses vale muito para massificar a linguagem - repassei para outros colegas que também estão iniciando na linguagem.


Mais uma vez agradeço exponencialmente as observações. Aos poucos vou domando a julia ;).

Answer (score 2):

from Doc:

> we are trying to fit the relationship `fun(x, a) = 0`

So, if you want to find elements of `a` in a way that: for each `xi,yi` in `[x0 y0]` => `a[1].*sin(a[2].*xi - a[3])==yi`, then the right way is:

```
fun(xy,a) = a[1].*sin(a[2].*xy[1] - a[3])-xy[2];
xy=hcat(x0,y0);
coefs,converged,iter = CurveFit.nonlinear_fit(xy,fun,a0,eps,maxiter);
```

Comment: Hi Reza Afzalan, Thank you for your help ;). I  I adjusted the code:

x0 = vec(x)
y0 = vec(y)

a = [1.5 1.5 1.0]
eps = 0.000000000001
maxiter= 200.0

fun(xy,a) = a[1].*sin(a[2].*xy[1] - a[3])-xy[2];

xy=hcat(x0,y0);
coefs,converged,iter = CurveFit.nonlinear_fit(xy,fun,a,eps,maxiter);

but the coefficients (0.26171239782898015,1.1472347006194563,0.7051280422828665) are not correct (1.19211 , 0.494285, 0.198769).

Answer (score 2):

I found the [LsqFit package](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl) a bit simpler to use, just define first the model and "fit it" with your data:

```
using DataFrames, Plots, LsqFit

xa         = [0  0.200000000000000 0.400000000000000  1.00000000000000  1.60000000000000  1.80000000000000  2.00000000000000  2.60000000000000  2.80000000000000  3.00000000000000  3.80000000000000  4.80000000000000  5.00000000000000  5.20000000000000  6.00000000000000  6.20000000000000  7.40000000000000  7.60000000000000  7.80000000000000  8.60000000000000  8.80000000000000  9.00000000000000  9.20000000000000  9.40000000000000  10.0000000000000  10.6000000000000  10.8000000000000  11.2000000000000  11.6000000000000  11.8000000000000  12.2000000000000  12.4000000000000];
ya         = [-0.183440428023042  -0.131101157495126  0.0268875670852843 0.300000000120000  0.579048247883555  0.852605831272159  0.935180993484717  1.13328608090532  1.26893326843583  1.10202945535186  1.09201137189664  1.14279083803453  0.811302535321072  0.909735376251797  0.417067545528244  0.460107770989798  -0.516307074859654  -0.333994077331822  -0.504124744955962  -0.945794320817293  -0.915934553082780  -0.975458595671737  -1.09943707404275  -1.11254211607374  -1.29739980589100  -1.23440439602665  -0.953807504156356  -1.12240274852172  -0.609284630192522  -0.592560286759450  -0.402521296049042  -0.510090363150962];
x0         = vec(xa)
y0         = vec(ya)
xbase      = collect(linspace(minimum(x0),maximum(x0),100))
p0         = [1.2, 0.5, 0.5]                                                      # initial value of parameters
fun(x0, p) = p[1] .* sin.(p[2] .* x0 .- p[3])                                     # definition of the model
fit        = curve_fit(fun,x0,y0,p0)                                              # actual fitting job
yFit       = [fit.param[1] * sin(fit.param[2] * x - fit.param[3]) for x in xbase] # building the fitted values
# Plotting..
scatter(x0, y0, label="obs")
plot!(xbase, yFit, label="fitted")
```

[image: plotted data]

Note that using LsqFit does not solve the problem of dependency from initial conditions highlighted by Gomiero..